# How to show the time when the blockchain contract called?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, react

I want to show the time when blockchain contract called.

I am currently saving the time in the blockchain using a method like this

```
function userCheckIn(uint placeid) public {
    userCount++;
    checkins[userCount] = Checkin(placeid, msg.sender, new Date(now * 1000));
}
```

However, `Date` says Identifier not found or not unique.

Could you give me any advise, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create a **JS object Date**. Obviously, it won't work since it's not JS but Solidity.

If you want the current time when the function is called (so mined), you can use `now`.

Read more [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties).

Comment: Thank you! When I used `now`, that only showed numbers like this `1555650125
1555651118
1555651169`